# How do I create a wall of maps with item frames?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently came across this screenshot on the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map):

[image: Map wall]

When I try to put different maps in item frames adjacent to each other, they do not join. I can't get any number of maps to join into a single image, even when the maps adjacent should actually fit together.

How do I align maps in item frames to join as shown in the picture?

Comment: Have you tried setting your display settings to Fancy?  
EDIT: Can I see what it looks like on your side?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: May I see what it looks like when you attempt to remake it with your world? (Screenshot with F2)

Comment: What is the earliest version of PC minecraft that expands the map beyond the item frame? I am running 1.6.2 Forge with IC2 mod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I am really disorganised. I had my maps all over the place and couldn't wrap my head around it.

I started a new creative world to try from scratch, but this time I organised every map in my inventory in the same formation that it would be on the item frames:

[image]

I then created each map one by one, starting with the center, making sure I put it back in the correct position afterwards:

[image]

I did this until I had filled out every map:

[image]

After I had filled out all of the maps I put them in item frames row by row until I got this final result:

[image]

Comment: Do these maps need to be fully zoomed out or can it be the smaller maps?

Comment: I used the smallest 128 x 128 maps. I haven't tried it with zoomed out maps but I assume it is the same principle.

Comment: What a pretty map...